apt-get does not prompt for configuration file replacement when installing new version of a package
I'm working on installing a package and apparently facing a problem with dpkg.
I've included the full path of a configuration file in the conffiles, built the package, and installed it (via apt-get).
Then I've modified the configuration file, rebuilt the package, and installed the new version (apt-get once more).
I expected the dpkg asked me how to proceed with the configuration file but instead, it overwrites the old configuration file with the new one.
I working on a debian 11 (bullseye) and have no specific configuration options for apt-get or dpkg.
As far as I can understand the default behaviour of apt-get/dpkg should be to ask the user for replacement of the old configuration file.
Can someone cast a light on this apparent misbehavior?

Did you modify the installed configuration file, or the configuration file shipped in the package?

@StephenKitt No I did not modify the installed configuration file, it was shipped in the package

OK, so muru’s answer explains the behaviour you’re seeing.

This is the expected behaviour. Only if the conffile has modifications outside of the package management system, like when a system administrator has modified it, will dpkg prompt on what needs to be done. Otherwise, it's a straightforward replacement of old defaults with new defaults. Any significant changes would have been announced in the NEWS, and it is expected that users would check them before performing significant updates.
